# WPF store layout in resources

Tags: wpf

I have application where default Window's borders switched off

Window tag definition looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TEA.UI.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Title" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
```

Inside Window tag, there is Grid panel, it contains several Rectangle shapes and few other grids.

It looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- WINDOW BACKGROUND -->
    <Rectangle Stroke="#FF214E80" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF193C6C" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF2A65A4" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!-- // WINDOW BACKGROUND -->

    <!-- HEADER HIGHLIGHT2 -->
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="62" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#00193C6C" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#4C96ABC3" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!-- // HEADER HIGHLIGHT2 -->
<Grid>
    ....
</Grid>
```

These rectangle shapes are used in other window dialogs as well.

My questions are:

How would it be possible to store these recatangles inside WPF resource dictionary?

How would I be able to reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution was quite simple
WPF UserControl did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style in your resource dictionary for these items with setters for each property--one included below.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" x:Key="WindowBackground">
  <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF214E80"/>
</Style>
```

Then in your window you can reference the style as such..

```
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource WindowBackground}"/>
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, but that would will have to create separate style for each rectangle.

Comment: Do you have your resources declared at the application level or on a per-project basis? If you're re-using your references you should have them at the app level since your memory usage will increase each time you declare them at a per-project basis. And yes, you will need 2 styles regardless.